# Paypal and Jquery UI Price Slider

Tags: jquery, user-interface, paypal, slider

I've search the internet for about a week now! And don't seem to have any help on the area I'm stuck on.

So I thought I'd sign up and see if you wonderful people can help.

I've got 2 Jquery UI Slider, One for height and one of length (Going from 1-10 and 1-20 metres)
They have fields underneath that show the height and length then from that I have a bit of code that calculates a price..

Heres a snipit of my code..

```
    function calculate() {
    var width = $("#width-value").val();
    var height = $(".height-value").val();
    var inter = (parseFloat(height) + parseFloat(width));
    var times = inter * 10;
    var total = times + 75;

    $("#total-value").val(total);

};
```

Which also works exactly how I would like it too :D.

But heres my problem, I would like to connect it up to paypal, but as I have no static value I'm not sure how to go about it, I just want one Buy it now button, but the price would change, depending on the whats selected by the sliders, Does anyone have any idea if this is possible/safe?

I hope I went into enough detail, any help would be appreicated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For that you'd need to take a look at Paypal's **[Direct Payment](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside)** API.

Quoted from the source itself:

> For each payment, *Direct Payment API* takes the billing address, transaction amount, credit card information, and item information as inputs. Within seconds, the API returns a confirmation that the transaction has been processed.

**Please note:** Direct Payment API is not a stand-alone product. You are required to use *Direct Payment API* and *Express Checkout* together as part of the *Website Payments Pro* solution.